# Default value when fetching from a list in R

Tags: r, clojure

In clojure you can do this:

```
(def x {:a 1 :b 2})
(def y (or (:c x) 111))
```

In R you can do like this:

```
x = list(a = 1, b = 2)
y = {
    if ("c" %in% names(x)) {
        x$c
    } else {
        111
    }
}
```

It works, but is far less elegant. Is there a better way?

Comment: Not even one of your `{` in the `y` definition is needed.

Comment: I presume you mean `if ("a" %in% names(x))`.

Comment: Ah, a typo. It should be `x$c` instead.

Comment: Just a tiny note: in clojure you can do `(:c x 111)` to get the default value of 111. No `or` necessary.

Comment: @Andre Ah, yes. I vaguely remembered there is something like that. Cool.

Answer (score 4):

Defined in `dplyr` but not exported (https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/R/utils.r#L81) is the operator

```
"%||%" <- function(x, y) if(is.null(x)) y else x
```

then you can write it

```
x$a %||% 1111
```

Answer (score 2):

This achieves the same result using much less space:

```
 x <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
 y <- ifelse("c" %in% names(x), x$a, 111)
```